# How can I implement ChannelFactory and WCF assembly sharing with Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, .net-4.0, channelfactory

The preferred WCF implementation is with assembly sharing and ChannelFactory - a single instance of the contract means any service changes only need be made in one place, there's no proxy to update or maintain, etc.

I'd like to implement ChannelFactory with Silverlight. I've had enough of RIA Domain Services etc.

My Silverlight application can only reference Silverlight assemblies - fair enough. So I put the `ServiceContract` interfaces in a Silverlight assembly and reference that from my server and client.

The problem is that when I go to run my server (which is IIS hosted, in this case) I get

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The Silverlight assembly containing the `ServiceContract` is built with a different version of `System.ServiceModel` than my server is using (which is .NET 4.0). How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply,

using [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx);

Answer (score 2):

This non compatibility with silverlight and .net, is partially artificial, and can be worked around, if you know how to do it.

http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/12/Reusing-NET-Assemblies-in-Silverlight

Comment: What you could do is provide at least main points of this work around here as an answer, instead of just providing like to external site. This answer becomes useless on the second link becomes dead.